# AWS CloudWatch & Xray Intergration with my Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, health-monitoring, aws-xray, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am deploying a SaaS application using AWS resources like ECS-Fargate, RDS etc. and I decided to do the monitoring using AWS CloudWatch and AWS Xray because I am only using AWS resources for my deployment.

My problem is, I need a way to integrate the Log, infrastructure health, performance analytic, real-time alert server status change etc. on my SaaS application Admin dashboard.

Is there is way to get the API form AWS and integrate or is there a better way to go about this.

I have created a dashboard for displaying my CPU Utilization, Log Groups etc.

I need a way, if possible, to get this real time data on my Admin dashboard or a better recommendation on how to monitor this resources/infrastructure and get the real time data on my SaaS application admin dashboard